# interlink two functions to display same result using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I want to design a dropdown such that it takes value range as 10, 20,30,50,70,100,150,200,300,700,1000,2000, and 5000. I also want two buttons for which I  can assign value_up or value_down. which will get value range as mentioned above. Drop down will allow user to select values from above set manually where as value_up or value_down would allow to increase or decrease value for the above range. Could you please help me to achieve this using javascript? I have a basic functionality written here bu it is not doing the function as explained above.

html:

10 μV
                20 μV
                30 μV
                50 μV
                70 μV
                100 μV
                150 μV
                200 μV
                300 μV
                700 μV
                1000 μV
                2000 μV
                5000 μV

```
        <span type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 1000px;padding: 4px;" id="btn09" onclick="sensitivity_Down(this.value);"></span><br>Sensitivity</span>
```

Javascript:

```
function sensitivity_Up(x){
            sensitivityFlag = 1;
            sens = 1*x/100;
            draw_TeeChart();
        }

        function sensitivity_Down(y){
            sensitivityFlag= -1;
            sens = 1*y/100;
            draw_TeeChart();
        }
```

image:
[image: Similar to this]

something similar to this example here http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/xwj67/

I want to pass the values of a selection tag to a button attribute so that the button can have same selection group as input attribute.

for instance in the code below sensitivity has a range selection from 10 to 5000 which can be shown in a dropdown list. I want to have this selection range read directly from Sensitivity into button without having a dropdown. How can i use the previous selection value range into button?

```
 <select name="sensitivity" id="sensitivitySelect" onchange="sensitivity(this.value);"  style="border-radius: 25px;color:black;background-color:white; ">
                        <option value= 10>10 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 20>20 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 30>30 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 50>50 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 70>70 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 100 selected="selected">100 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 150>150 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 200>200 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 300>300 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 700>700 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 1000 >1000 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 2000>2000 &mu;V</option>
                        <option value= 5000>5000 &mu;V</option>
                    </select></span>

                    <span type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up" style="border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 1000px;padding: 4px;" id="btn08" onclick="sensitivity(this.value);"></span>               
                    <span type="button" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down" style="border: 2px solid white;border-radius: 1000px;padding: 4px;" id="btn09" onclick="Sensitivity.value.sensitivity_Down(this.value);"></span><br>Sensitivity</span>
```

Comment: What does interlink mean?

Comment: reflect values of arrow_down or arrow up in the the selected dropdown box. Here both dropdown values and arrow functions are giving me different values. I want them to reflect same values.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like each sens is being calculated separately. All you need is this outside the functions:

```
var sens;
```

Comment: any demo please. I don't want to calculate arrow_up and arrow_down functions separately though. want them to interlink.